# Send string containing html in url without removing special chars

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send a message which is a string containing an icon which is a html element but when i pass it in my web service url it removes all special chars . Is there a way to leave it as a string without removing these special chars ?

the string that i want to pass is

```
      var body= "hello <img src="/assets/smile.png">";
```

the web service url is :

```
  return this.http.get('  http://localhost:44435/Projet/AddMsessage?body=' +body+ '&idSender=' + idSender + '&idDiscussion=' + idDiscussion);
```

but the probleme that when i execute the webservice it changes into this :

```
http://localhost:44435/Projet/AddMsessage?body=halo%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fsmile.png%22%3E%20&idSender=1&idDiscussion=1
```

it removes the  < , / , " ,> chars

Comment: The encoded URL looks OK to me. You could decode it at the receiving end. By the way, the inner quotes in `body` should probably be single quotes (or the double quotes should be escaped).

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use `HttpClient#get`'s second parameter to pass URL parameters. See [the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters) for more information.

Your code becomes:

```js
return this.http.get('http://localhost:44435/Projet/AddMsessage', {
  params: new HttpParams()
    .set('body', body)
    .set('idSender', idSender)
    .set('idDiscussion', idDiscussion)
});
```

If you don't, if your parameters' values contain characters such as `?` or `&`, they'll screw up your URL as Angular has no way of knowing where each parameter "stops".

However, it's perfectly normal for special characters to be url encoded. `<` becomes `%3C` and so on.

Comment: Jeto i just tried your answer but still the same probleme it didn't work :/

Comment: @AOUADISlim What do you mean, what exactly is happening? Can you paste the final URL that's being requested (from your browser's console)?

Comment: Also, "AddMsessage" is suspicious, shouldn't it be "AddMessage"?

Comment: Jeto yes :p this is the final url 
http://localhost:44435/Projet/AddMsessage?body=halo%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fsmile.png%22%3E%20&idSender=1&idDiscussion=1

Comment: See my edit; I actually misread your question a bit. Your original URL *should* be fine, though it's not recommended to pass parameters like that.

Comment: What doesn't work/what is happening? Please be more specific.

Comment: i want the url to be http://localhost:44435/Projet/AddMsessage?body="hello <img src="/assets/smile.png">"+ etc
 but instead i always get this 
http://localhost:44435/Projet/AddMsessage?body=halo%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22%2Fassets%2Fsmile.png%22%3E%20&idSender=1&idDiscussion=1

it's with special chars didn't know how to make it keep the string like it is

Comment: It's normal as my answer states, and everyone else did tell you as well (@Soumare, @ConnorsFan). Special characters are supposed to be URL-encoded, they'll be decoded automatically when reaching the API endpoint.

Comment: sooo is there any way to make what i want to do

Comment: There is no reason to.

Comment: so u advice me to change my work because it won't work ?

Comment: Just use the code from this answer, and your parameters should be properly received on the endpoint's side (without the encoded characters). I don't really know what else to say.